# My game's physics are behaving non-deterministically and I'm not sure where to start to solve the issue

Tags: unity, physics, determinism

I'm trying to get my game to behave deterministically just on my system. I can get it to behave deterministically if the scene is freshly loaded, but if I attempt to just reset the scene to its "fresh" state from scripts, I get different outcomes despite identical player input.

A bit of background on the game: It is essentially just cars (controlled by physics) finding their ways to their destinations. At the start of the simulation, these cars are instantiated pseudo-randomly using a seed which stays the same each simulation. When the cars reach their destination they are deleted using Destroy().

The simulation can be ended early in which case all cars that remain in the scene (the ones that have not yet reached their destinations) are deleted with Destroy(). This step is achieved by cars adding themselves to a list when they are instantiated, this list is then used to Destroy each car. I was initially iterating through the list with foreach and just running Destroy(). I read somewhere that this was bad practice and instead used a for loop that iterated backwards through the list. This seemed to improve determinism. (Before this change the simulation would vary perhaps on the 2nd or 3rd retry, whereas after this change determinism would fail on the 6th or 7th retry).

If I reload the scene, I always get the same result (I may have to resort to this as a solution, but I'd much rather be able to solve it without reloading the scene). I also have enhanced determinism checked in the project settings.

I'm just a bit lost as where to even begin isolating what is causing my determinism issues. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Also everything is in FixedUpdate.

My experience is very similar to [this post on the Unity forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/reset-physics.862081/)

Comment: To help you solve this, we'll need your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem. Try making a copy of the project and stripping it down to the bare minimum that still demonstrates divergence after resetting the state in script. Keep in mind that the PhysX and Box2D physics engines used for Unity's built-in physics are not designed to give determinism guarantees — they prioritize performance above exactly repeatable results, so if you need perfect reproducibility you may need to implement those features in your own code or use another library/package.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. Just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something obvious.